# Display message at the bottom of screen after successful posting of data in html form

Tags: php

I have a HTML form which accepts inputs and a php file to insert the data into the custom table.

I would like to display a  "Data successfully saved" message after inserting data into database. I am able to get the page to stay on the same page but not sure **how to display a success message**.

The PHP code is below:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once "wp-load.php";
require_once "dbconfig.php"

global $wpdb, $current_user;
$current_user=wp_get_current_user();
$current_username = $current_user->user_login;
$table_name='xxx';
$first_name=$_POST['first_name'];
$last_name= $_POST['last_name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$telephone=$_POST['telephone'];

$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare(
"
INSERT INTO $table_name
( first_name, last_name, email,telephone,user_name)
VALUES ( %s, %s, %s,%s,%s )
",
$first_name,$last_name,$email,$telephone,$current_username 
) );
//Staying on same page.
header("Location:http://xxx/");
exit();
```

Answer (score 1):

`$wddb->query()` returns a `boolean`/numbered output.

If we put this output in `if` condition, it will evaluate to `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

So, simply, take a flag:

```
$flag = $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare(
"
INSERT INTO $table_name
( first_name, last_name, email,telephone,user_name)
VALUES ( %s, %s, %s,%s,%s )
",
$first_name,$last_name,$email,$telephone,$current_username 
) );
```

And print the condition depending upon the `flag`

```
if ($flag) {
 echo 'Data saved successfully.';
}
```

> Return #Return
>
> (int|bool) Boolean true for CREATE, ALTER, TRUNCATE and DROP queries.
>   Number of rows affected/selected for all other queries. Boolean false
>   on error.

[Rererence:](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/query/)

Comment: tried the code suggested by you. the message displays but there is also an error:   Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /xx/xx.php:39) in /xx/xxx.php on line 42

Comment: The `header("Location:http://xxx/");` issues warning if anything is output on browser. Either comment the `header...` code or add `ob_start()` in the beginning of the file as it saves file output to buffer and `header("Location...` will work.

Comment: But, you want two contradictory things: 1) Output a string on page 2) Redirect the page. Only one of it will work.

Comment: Okay, basically the message should display and the page should refresh as a blank page. IS this possible?

Comment: Yes, put `die(); after the `echo` success message statement.

Comment: Once I add die(); the message displays correctly, but the page does not refresh to the original data entry page. My code at the end is : if($flag) {
     alert( 'Data saved successfully.');
           }
           die();
header("Location:http://xxx/");

exit(); ?>   xxx being my original data entry page

Comment: Could somebody please help here? This is really urgent!!